# Serializing a listener in Java

Tags: java, serialization, listener

Is it possible to serialize a listener in Java? I'm thinking of having a listener like this:

```
public abstract class Listener implements Serializable{
    public abstract void callback(Object o);
}
```

which gets used as an anonymous class and sent to a remote machine to be executed:

```
final Object param1, param2, ...
Listener l = new Listener(){
    @Override
    public void callback(Object o){
        //do something with param1, param2, ... here
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the Object objects will be serialized, not the method itself, no? So it depends if those are serializable I would say.

Comment: How would I specify a callback method then, if it can't be serialized?

Comment: Can you provide the reason you want to do this? This is a really unorthodox thing, so I am curious.

Comment: What is the exact purpose ? I can't figure out any case where you would have to do this.

Comment: I guess in some ways I'm trying to emulate AJAX in web applications. But not exactly. I have some proxy objects held on a local machine. I would like to perform an operation (the callback) on the remote machine the proxy refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing with RMI and dynamic class loading.

The way it works is:

1. the *data* will be serialized.
2. the *particular class used* will be sent as a URL, and then downloaded from the URL by a `ClassLoader` on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure this is what I needed.